# Can I set HttpClient to always read full response in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

So I have read [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) that i order to read full response including headers
I must do

```
  this.client<MyType>.get('someurl', { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(val=>doit);
```

1. Is there a way to set it up globally, without adding options to every request?
2. If I set `{ observe: 'response' }` will the `val` still be of `MyType` or it will be `HttpResponse` ??
3. Is it possible to force parsing of full response in case of `HttpErrorResponse`

Option 3 would be the best for me, as I require to read response header in interceptor that holds error cause - but only in case of error response. I don't have to read headers in 200 responses.

Answer (score 3):

1. It should work if you put `observe:'response` in a `HttpInterceptor`

   `request.clone({ setParams: { observe: 'response' },...})`
2. Your response will be of type `HttpResponse<MyType>`
3. You could try always observing the response, but in your interceptor you map the result to the response body, so that the original caller in your service only gets the data it needs. If there is an error, read the response headers and return data accordingly

Comment: 1) looks promising. I will give it a shot tomorrow. I hope it will solve the issue

Comment: is this will required to use res.json() like old http ??

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi No, with the new `HttpClient`, response data is automatically converted to json, unless you specify otherwise using `responseType` param

Comment: @David how to remap to original `observe` target? What if caller used `{observer:respones}` It seems that I cannot get that info from ther `request` object ;/